# optimizing harris corner detector

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, convolution, corner-detection

I'm trying to optimize my Harris corner detector to make it fast enough for real time feature extraction that will ultimately be used in SLAM applications.

The traditional harris corner detector follows these steps:

1. calculate image derivatives (gradients) Ix and Iy using image convolution kernel (**k_dx** and **k_dy**).
2. calculate second-order derivatives Ixx = Ix^2, Iyy = Iy^2 and Ixy = Ix*Iy.
3. Filter the three second-order derivatives from step 2 using a Gaussian kernel (**k_gaussian**).
4. Calculate the Harris response using the formula stated in the literature.

So far so good. I've implemented the above steps and have a working program. However we know that convolution is a commutative algebra, meaning that:

1. f # g = g # f
2. f # (g # h) = (f # g) # h
3. f # (g + h) = (f # g) + (f # h)
4. constant * (f # g) = (constant * f) # g

where (#) is the convolution operation.

So in essence we can combine various kernels in order to reduce the computation time.
I was hoping to use this to my advantage to combine the image gradient kernel used in step (1) with the Gaussian kernel used in step (3) to reduce the computation time. Unfortunately step (2) prevents me from doing so, as:
 [(**IM** # **k_dx**)^2] # **k_gaussian** =! (**IM** # **k_dx** # **k_gaussian**)^2

where **IM** is the image. so the two kernels cannot be combined.

My question: is there a way to do this or is it simply impossible? If it is impossible, then is there a way to calculate a combined kernel that **approximates** the true answer. Even if it a poor approximation it may be worth it to reduce the computation cost.

In case you are wondering, i'm already using CUDA to perform my image convolutions on the GPU and the corner detector is already fairly quick. but i need to improve it further in order to allocate a bigger slice of the time frame for the remaining SLAM algorithms.

Comment: There is already a good answer. Two things spring to mind: (a) pick a feature detector that is optimised for GPU/CUDA. (b) premature optimisation. If the corner detector is quick, how much will you gain if you double the speed? It sounds like it might move from 5% of time to 2.5% of time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct combination of kernels to use convolution is not possible. The Ixx = Ix^2, Iyy = Iy^2 and Ixy = Ix*Iy is NOT found by convolution (it is not linear).

Some tricks for optimization can be found in "LOCOCO: LOW COMPLEXITY CORNER DETECTOR"